# Is there a Go equivalent of Python's itertools.combinations?

Tags: python, go, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to find all possible combinations of a set in `go`, and I've only been able to find solutions for how to do this using Python's itertools to get all the tuples possible. For example, if I have the original set

`['0', '1', '2']`,

then the possible combinations would be

`[['0'], ['1'], ['2'], ['0', '1'], ['0', '2'], ['1', '2'], ['0', '1', '2']]`

I can't figure out how to do it without repeating sets, like ['0', '1'] and ['1', '0'].

Thank you!!

Comment: Just googleing *go combinations* gives [this](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mxschmitt/golang-combinations)

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this tool](https://github.com/ernestosuarez/itertools) can help you get the required combinations.

Ex:

```golang
// Generating combinations Slices of integers
// combinations of r = 3 elements chosen from iterable
r := 3
iterable := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}

for v := range CombinationsInt(iterable, r) {
      fmt.Println(v)
}
```

output:

```
[1 2 3]
[1 2 4]
[1 3 4]
[2 3 4]
```